# I need sugestions about database problems

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a website which uses a database with more then 1.5 million records. Now I got to a point where the web hosting company suspends my site for once in a while. The reason is because the queries which executes to the server overloads the system. Please , give me some advice about how i could resolve it !

Query example:

```
SELECT id,a,b,c,d,e,f 
FROM table 
WHERE a LIKE '%GHEORGHE%' OR b LIKE '%GHEORGHE%' 
   OR c LIKE '%GHEORGHE%' OR  a LIKE '%GHE.%' OR b LIKE '%GHE.%' 
   OR c LIKE '%GHE.%' OR  a LIKE '%AURELIA%' 
   OR b LIKE '%AURELIA%' OR c LIKE '%AURELIA%' OR a LIKE '%PERSOANA%' 
   OR b LIKE '%PERSOANA%' OR c LIKE '%PERSOANA%' OR 0) 
   AND id != $id 
ORDER BY f ASC 
LIMIT 10
```

This query executes in 2 seconds .

Comment: Share your query, maybe it can be optimised.

Comment: Either buy a more powerful server or optimize the queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relatively, 1.5 million records is not big at all.  The problem is that the clause LIKE '%word%' is very expensive in terms of processing.  Especially if the fields are TEXT fields and not indexed.

- If possible, create indexes for all the fields searched for
- If possible, simplify the WHERE conditions. For example LIKE '%GHE.%' might probably be changed to LIKE '%GHE%', and if LIKE '%GHE%' already satisfy the search criteria, you do not need to have LIKE '%GHEORGHE%' anymore

[I am assuming the "OR 0) " near the end of your query is just a typing mistake]

Answer (score 5):

Buy a dedicated server.

Comment: (In response to the now-deleted comment on a VPS depending on budget) True. Either way, the point is that shared servers are not designed for applications that uses a database that big.

Comment: That's just about the best advice one could give without seeing some of the queries.

Comment: @Kolink that is why I deleted my comment, a VPS might not suit OP's need if he is using a large database.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your queries might be rather inefficient. It is worth examining the queries you perform and seeing if you can make less - by performing joins, caching data that isn't going to change very often, or simply being a bit more clever with how you collect and use the data to avoid unnecessary queries.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your situation maybe you could break your tables up to shrink the queries. For example if you know a user from a certain country or on a certain page only needs records that meet a certain criteria or have certain properties you might be able to point them to the right table ahead of time and shrink the size of rows you are querying from.

That's a general idea that could work but it really depends on what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

That query won't execute at all because it's not syntactically correct.

I'm no expert on database optimisation but I do know that all those wildcards will take a long time to get through. 2 seconds is a lifetime in DB query execution terms. Having id != $id is also a very intensive condition to check.

Edit: Do you have indexes on a, b etc? They can make a big difference to speed. Your multiple us of "OR" will slow the query down. Perhaps you could break this into multiple queries and do what you want using PHP?